# How to pass a variable as an object instance in Django function

Tags: python, django, function

I have a function

```
def update_field():
    ...
    ...
    book.country = country_id
    ...
```

I have the same piece of code in several places and I need to make a separate function for it. For example

```
def update_field(obj_field):
    ...
    ...
    obj_field = country_id
    ...
```

but when I try to call the function it doesn't work

```
country = book.country
update_field(country)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setattr would do the job

```
def update_field(obj, field_name):
    ...
    ...
    setattr(obj, field_name, country_id)
    ...
```

If you would want to edit related model field you should do:

```
def update_field(obj, field_name):
    ...
    ...
    related_model_name, related_model_field_name = field_name.split('.')
    related_model = getattr(obj, related_model_name)
    setattr(related_model, related_model_field_name, 'Abba')
    related_model.save()
    ...
```

Comment: One more question
How can I pass related model field?
For example: 
obj=book and field_name=booktext.about

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Maybe, you can also help me with this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72319251/how-to-pass-a-variable-in-a-function-to-update-many-to-many-field